# Enzyme\Protein amounts in cancer

Tags: cancer

I am searching for source, that providing information about enzymes\proteins, in different types of cancers, that their amount in cell is significantly higher - comparing to normal, healthy cell.

Some pathways that exist in cancer in much more higher amounts.

For example - Telomerase.

Is there some sort of database for this information?

Comment: You could try expression atlas: http://www.ebi.ac.uk/gxa/home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The [dbDEPC 2.0](http://lifecenter.sgst.cn/dbdepc/index.do) database for example.
If you want to extend your search to pathways the best database I know of is the [KEGG](http://www.genome.jp/kegg/pathway.html).

There are multiple databases out there. You might want to look at this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_biological_databases).

By the way what you are looking for is called a **cancer proteomic signature**.